# Reinstall PHP on Fedora 22 Installed PHP was compiled

Tags: php, fedora, compiled, reinstall

I'd like to know how can I reinstall PHP via dnf and make it default for apache. My problem is that I have a installed version of PHP but it was compiled and as I'm facing several problems with modules I didn't compile I thought it'd be easier do it this way. I'd like to remove this version that's installed too.

Here it's the result of how it's working on my machine right now:

```
$ uname -a
Linux dev 4.4.6-200.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 22:13:40 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Fedora)
Server built:   Jan  4 2016 13:05:47

$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php-5.6.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/zip.so' - /opt/php-5.6.19/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/zip.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.19 (cli) (built: Mar 17 2016 10:26:07) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I'm just asking because I wasn't able to find how to do that here or several other places I've searched. Tks in advance.

Comment: did you try `dnf reinstall php`?

Comment: as the version is compiled I can't reinstall doing that, I tried dnf install php, but the version didn't become default for apache, for me install the version and the version I install via dnf be default in apache will suffice, tks in advance and tks Jakuje for editing.

Comment: so then `make install` once it was done for the first time is probably the way to go.

Comment: I don't want to do this way because is too much trouble, but tks